# Imported component does not show up on browser

Tags: reactjs

I'm really new in react and I'm having problems with this:
I create a class and imported it into the App.js file, like this:

The class:

```js
import React,{component} from "react"

class Begin extends component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>General Kenobi</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Begin;
```

then the App with the class imported:

```js
import './App.css';
import Begin from './example'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Hello there
      <Begin />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If I remove the  I see on the browser the strip "Hello there", but when I put it, nothing is shown, not even the "Hello there"

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

React class component need to extend from `Component` class *with capital letter C*

```js
import React, {Component} from "react"

class Begin extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>General Kenobi</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Begin;
```